# can't seem to run multiple commands in a loop in a windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, syntax

```
ECHO OFF 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
CD C:\Work\
FOR /D /r %%G in ("t*") DO (
   START C:\prg.exe %%G\input_1 %%G\input_2 %%G\cpp_output
   FOR /D /r %%H in (%%G\cpp_output\*.txt) DO (
        FOR /F %%i in ("%%H") DO (
            @set FN=%%~nxi DO (
                START C:\Work\compareResults.m %%G\matlab_output\FN.txt    %%G\cpp_output\FN.txt
            )
        )
    )
)
PAUSE
```

I have been trying to get this .bat code to run but it doesn't work - a window opens and closes quickly - i.e prg is not run. However, when I run:

```
ECHO OFF 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
CD C:\Work\
FOR /D /r %%G in ("t*") DO (
    START C:\prg.exe %%G\input_1 %%G\input_2 %%G\cpp_output
)
PAUSE
```

prg is run. I guess there seems to be a problem with the extra commands but I just don't know what the problem is. 
According to http://ss64.com/nt/for.html one can have a few commands in a single for and they can be in different lines. However that didn't work so I tried using & to have multiple commands and I've also tried using the caret (^) for breaking lines. None of these seem to work and I can't even really debug anything since the batch window disappears too fast. Any ideas for what I am doing wrong? Or even how to debug the .bat program?

Comment: Start a CMD console, navigate to your file and run it by typing it's name and ENTER. This way you will be able to see the output instead of just a window opening and closing. Plz tell us what the error message is saying.

Comment: `@set ... DO(` is not a valid command. Remove the `DO(`

Comment: @MichaelS I get DO ( was unexpected at this time

Comment: PA - in what way is the command incorrect? I tried moving the DO to the next lineand I am still getting the same error message

Comment: This means bad syntax. Check my answer below.

Comment: problem solved - in addition to what michealS and PA said , apparently there has to be a space between DO and ( which was causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
       @set FN=%%~nxi DO(
   START C:\Work\compareResults.m %%G\matlab_output\FN.txt    %%G\cpp_output\FN.txt))))
```

This won't work. This is bad syntax. DO can't stand behind a SET command. In your case DO goes only with FOR:

```
FOR something DO (
    codeline 1
    codeline 2
    ...
    codeline n
)
```

If you want several command lines to be executed within a FOR block you just have to write them between the brackets (), each command in a new line.

However, there is also a way to combine several commands in only one line (don't use it here): `command1&command2&...comandn` will execute commands 1 to n one after the other. They will be executed even if one of the commands throws an error. If you use && instead (`command1&&command2&&...comandn`), each command will only be executed if the previous command was proceeded without errors.

Comment: thanks! However , I removed the DO and I am still getting the same error message

Comment: I've also changed the FN to J and changed START C:\Work\compareResults.m %%G\matlab_output\FN.txt    %%G\cpp_output\FN.txt to START C:\Work\compareResults.m %%G\matlab_output\%%J.txt    %%G\cpp_output\%%J.txt but because I though that might be a problem but I am still getting the same error message :(